# Probability that both red and blue cards exist in a pack of 10 cards?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, puzzle

You are given a pack of 10 cards. Each card has 0.05 probability of being a red card and also 0.05 probability of being a blue card (red and blue cards are rare).

**What is the probability that the pack has at least 1 red card *and* at least 1 blue card?**

I tried solving this problem by enumerating all possible red and blue cards combination:
$$\mathbb{P}(\geq 1 \text{ red card and } \geq 1 \text{ blue card}) = \sum_{r=1}^9 \sum_{b=1}^{10 - r} {10 \choose r} {10 - r \choose b} 0.05^r 0.05^b (1 - 0.05 - 0.05)^{10-r-b}$$

However, this is very difficult to compute, especially if the number of cards in the pack gets larger (more than 10).

**Is there a more clever, simpler way to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a much simpler way to approach.  Consider the *opposite* event.  Here, that would be that you either had no red cards or you had no blue cards or both.

Let $A$ be the event you had no red, and $B$ the event you had no blue.  Your original question asks you to find $\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)$ which expands by standard identities as:

$$\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)=1 - \Pr(A\cup B) = 1 - \Pr(A)-\Pr(B)+\Pr(A\cap B)$$

That last expansion was due to Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

Each of the above in the final expression should be easy to calculate.  The probability no cards were red, well that is just the probability that all cards were non-red, and so on.

Comment: I see. Amazing! Thank you so much.